# When a word is too big go to the next line

Tags: android, textview

I have 2 textview one next to each other like this:

```
<com.mb.components.widget.MBLabel
                android:id="@+id/mbLabelValue"
                style="@style/MBHeadersValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?spacing_30"
                android:layout_marginEnd="?spacing_20"
                android:maxLines="2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mbLabelValue2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:text_style="normal" />

            <com.mb.components.widget.MBLabel
                android:id="@+id/mbLabelValue2"
                style="@style/MBHeadersValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?spacing_30"
                android:layout_marginStart="?spacing_20"
                android:maxLines="2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mbLabelValue"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:text_style="bold" />
```

The issue is that sometimes I have huge numbers and in this case I need the number to go to the second line. Usually this is easy because a text is fill with several words so the words that doesn't fit in the first one goes to the second one. But in this case one single word doesn't fit in the first line so I need to move part of this word to the second one.

This is how it looks like now when I have big numbers:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `android:lines` attribute.

Comment: @Maleesha97 I tried with that before and it didn't work

Comment: If u want to have these two `TextView` horizontal start and end  aligned you can use barrier ..   if not the you can use `FlexBoxLayout` as a container it will handle the text overflow automatically ..

Comment: @ADM this didn't work. Now the values are not in top of each other like in the image above but it is not going to the second line

Comment: Try using `constrainedWidth="true"`. See the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#dimensions-constraints).

Comment: @Cheticamp this solved the issue. If you add it as answer I will put the check to it